# JavaScript While loop returning "undefined" for first letter in array

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm currently learning the basics of 'while' and 'for' loops in JS. In the while loop below I'm attempting to print out each individual letter of the variable name, however the first letter of the string prints undefined and the remaining letters print out correctly. Any help in understanding this is greatly appreciated.

```
 var name = "Hello World!";
    var i = [];
    while (i < name.length) {
        console.log (name[i]);
        i ++;
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < name.length; j++) {
        console.log(name);
    }
```

Results:

```
undefined
e
l
l
o

W
o
r
l
d
!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
```

Comment: Why are you initializing `i` with an empty `[]` array instead of `0`? When you do `name[i]`, you're basically doing `name[""]`, which would be `undefined`. Then the increment changes `""` to `1` because the `++` coerces the empty array to the number `0`.

Comment: To be honest...I have no idea why I did it that way. I think I understand now though. So having it be equal to an empty array is replacing the first letter with and empty slot correct?

Comment: Sort of. All object properties in JavaScript are strings, so when you do o`name[i]`, it takes whatever the value of `i` is and converts it to a string. For an empty array, it gets converted to an empty string. An empty string is a valid property, but certainly won't have a value. So it's basically fetching a property that doesn't exist.

Comment: Wow that makes so much sense. Thank you very much, that just clarified quite a bit of confusion I've had on several problems I've tried working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please initialize "i" to zero before while loop.

```
var name = "Hello World!";
var i = 0;
while (i < name.length) {
    console.log (name[i]);
    i ++;
}

for (var j = 0; j < name.length; j++) {
    console.log(name);
}
```